# How to rsync to local folders from a Django view

Tags: python, django, rsync, subprocess

I have a site that requires the ability for a logged in admin to push a staging database to a live database. The first thing it does is dump the sql and push to the target database. This works fine, but when I go to rsync the folders containing the uploaded material, I get an error. This ONLY occurs when the script is called from within the view, not from the command line or python shell. Here is the function:

```
def copy_media(self, origin_folder, target_folder):
    command_string = "rsync -a %s %s" % (origin_folder, target_folder)
    return_code = subprocess.call(command_string, shell=True)
    return return_code
```

The return code is "12" when it errors. My best guess is that since there's a considerable delay before the script finishes executing, the view doesn't know how to properly wait for it to end. The other guess I had was that the paths somehow get screwed up from within the view.

Comment: could it potentially be due to user auth set on files? you could try the -o option. Did you try -v option on rsync to see if any warnings are issued?

Comment: I'll try that... Any ideas on best way to call rsync from a view?

Comment: Do not use this code in production unless you are very sure that `origin_folder` and `target_folder`, otherwise you are prone to a shell injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check permissions of your server, it may be different user/permissions from when you use the command line and thus not be able to perform that command.

Answer (score 2):

When you run the command through the view, the 'django' user is calling the command and may not have permission to perform it. You could try changing the owner of the directory prior to running rsync `os.chown(path, uid, gid)` and see if that gets you anywhere.

Also, if you run `rsync -avzP` you will get the additional verbose, compress, and partial/progress options which might provide more information to help you debug.